# using Caldav for synchronize

Tags: icalendar, caldav

I am going to realise service that will redirect user to add my calendar to his calendar list. I am going to use Caldav protocol. How can I add my calendar .ics to user? How can I synchronize all changes on user's calendar?

Comment: Are two different caldav servers involved, or are the calendars on the same caldav server?

Comment: I need one caldav server where I will save and update calendars

Comment: Hi Diana, are you sure you mean CalDav & synchronise (2 way)?   It is possible you mean that the service intends to provide a subscribable .ics feed (see RFC5545)  that users can then subscribe to (ie add the calendar to their calendar application.   They will then see updates, new events added to the feed, but will not be able to make updates in their application that are reflected back on your server.  IE NOT synchronise, but a one-way update from your server to them.

Comment: Hi! yes I mean service that provides .ics calendars. And I don't understand how to synchronise all updates on users' devices